# Return true if all letters of a pattern appear in a string?

Tags: javascript

```js
function match(string, pattern) {

  var letterFound;
  if (string.indexOf(pattern) != -1) {
    letterFound = true;
  } else letterFound = false;

  return letterFound
}

console.log(match("abcdef", "!A2B$")); //should return true
console.log(match("abcdef", "FAce")); //should return true
console.log(match("abcdef", "FG")); //should return false
```

The issue I'm having is that the function is supposed to look at a string and look at the pattern and return true if the string features all LETTERS are found in the string. It should ignore symbols included within a pattern. Simple javascript would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying your code doesn't work? Why? What does it do or not do that it shouldn't do or should do?

Comment: It just returns false, false, false. :(

Comment: Please see [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I tried the recommended searches already, but none of them returned the result I needed.

Comment: Here's a hint - A `String` is more-or-less an `Array` of characters and `indexOf` returns the index of a matching element. You can't use it to return multiple indices. You need a loop

Comment: Why do you think that all characters in `"!A2B$"` are in `"abcdef"`?

Comment: Also how on earth is `!A2B$` in any way a pattern related to `abcdef`?

Comment: String contains A & B, and should ignore numbers and symbols. Therefore, it should return true.,

Comment: @jayjay275 Why would it ignore numbers and symbols?

Comment: @Aluan Haddad, that's the function I'm trying to make. I just don't know how to. :(

Comment: Laziness is not appreciated.

Comment: @Aluan Haddad. It's not really laziness though, is it? I've tried writing it myself, researching what others have found and I still cannot get it to work. So no, it's not laziness, more that I'm asking for help which would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You honestly researched and couldn't find how to perform a case insensitive string comparison?

Comment: Yes. Can you provide a link? ._.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine.

```
function match(string, pattern) {
  string = string.toLowerCase(), pattern = patten.toLowerCase();
  for (var i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++) {
    if (string.indexOf(pattern[i]) != -1) {
      return true;
      break; // match found
    } else {
      continue; // no match, move to next character in the pattern
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Finally, it works! Looks almost like what I produced, but I didn't understand how to make the further step. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: you are welcome, please upvote the answer and accept it.

Comment: I've upvoted and accepted, but people have down voted me to oblivion that it won't appear publicly or something like that.